# go-plugin net/rpc gob: local interface type *interface {} can only be decoded from remote interface type; received concrete type

Tags: go, plugins, hashicorp

How to pass a concrete type as an argument to the hashicorp [go-plugin](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-plugin)?

I took their [example](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-plugin/tree/master/examples/basic) and tried to add a parameter.

```golang
type Foo struct {
    Name string
}

func (g *GoDataRPC) Greet(foo Foo) string {
    var resp string
    err := g.client.Call("Plugin.Greet", &foo, &resp)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // Error: gob: local interface type *interface {} can only be decoded from remote interface type; received concrete type Foo
    }
    return resp
}

...

func (s *GoDataRPCServer) Greet(args interface{}, resp *string) error {
    *resp = s.Impl.Greet(args.(Foo))
    return nil
}
```

I've got `panic: gob: local interface type *interface {} can only be decoded from remote interface type; received concrete type Foo`

I was able to make it work by making `Foo` an interface and registering it to gob, which is not what I want.

```golang
func init() {
    gob.Register(new(Foo))
}
```

**EDIT:**
The `net/rpc` shows the exact same example working but `go-plugin` don't:

```
args = &Args{7, 8}
reply = new(Reply)
err = client.Call("Arith.Mul", args, reply)
```

Comment: In `Greet(foo Foo) string` try `var args interface{} = foo` and then pass `&args` instead of `&foo` to `client.Call`.

Comment: Thank you @mkopriva but it doesn't work. Firstly it says `gob: type not registered for interface: go_plugin.Foo` and after registering it to gob it says `Unexpected EOF`.